# Display SQL results in rows instead of a single line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

Table Offices:

```
OfficeID    MainAddId   SubAddId1   SubAddId2   PortAddId1
-------     --------    --------    --------    --------
  2             1           2           3           5
```

Table Address:

```
AddressID   Street          City            ZipCode     State
-------     --------        --------        --------    --------
  1         Forest Ave      New York        10001       New York
  2         Morris St       Philadelphia    19019       Pennsylvania
  3         David St        Raleigh         27513       North Carolina
```

Table Port:

```
PortID      PortName            Street          City            ZipCode     State
-------     -------             --------        --------        --------    --------
  5         New York Harbour    Bay St          New York        10001       New York
```

I want to write an SQL request such that if any of the addresses Id in the office table is not null,
it will return the list of addresses in a list like:

```
AddressID   Street          City            ZipCode     State
-------     --------        --------        --------    --------
1           Forest Ave      New York        10001       New York
2           Morris St       Philadelphia    19019       Pennsylvania
3           David St        Raleigh         27513       North Carolina
5           Bay St          New York        10001       New York
```

Any help on how I can do this please?  Thanks

Here is what I tried (partly cause it's not working):

```
select *
from Office offi
left join Address add1 on offi.MainAddId = add1.AddressID
left join Address add2 on offi.SubAddId1= add2.AddressID
where offi.OfficeID = 2;
```

However, this is returning the addresses on a single line.

Comment: Except the fact that the design is very poor (wth is that table "Offices" in term of UML?), it is very hard to understand what kind of query you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Hybris95I modified the question and added what I tried,  The issue is that since the Office table is storing different address Id, I don't know how to make a join with the Address or Port tables so I can retrieve the different addresses in different rows.  Like get a list of addresses for that office.

Comment: You should take a look at PIVOT instruction https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple joins if you really need them. Instead of that, you can use `OR` after `ON` in join.

I solved using `UNION`:

```
select a.AddressID, a.street, a.city, a.zipcode, a.state
from offices o
inner join address a on (o.MainAddid = a.addressId or o.subaddid1 = a.addressid or o.subaddid2 = a.addressid)

union

select p.PortId, p.street, p.city, p.zipcode, p.state
from offices o
inner join port p on p.portId = o.PortAddId1
```

Check demo on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7052a1090058be58686c6e8a04b1ff37)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one query :

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  (   SELECT  AddressID, Street, City, ZipCode, State
              FROM  address
            UNION
            SELECT  PortID, Street, City, ZipCode, State
              FROM  Port) w
 WHERE  addressid IN (   SELECT Addresses
                           FROM (   SELECT  OfficeID, MainAddId, SubAddId1, SubAddId2, PortAddId1
                                      FROM  Offices) p
                             UNPIVOT (   Addresses
                                               FOR Offices IN (MainAddId, SubAddId1, SubAddId2, PortAddId1)) AS unpvt );
```

Comment: Hi, for give best feed back please read help center and get tour from this link : stackoverflow.com/tour